# Automated download of NetCDF file

Tags: python, netcdf

Just wondered if anyone could help I'm trying to download a NetCDF file from the internet within my code. The website is wish to download from is:

http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/cgi-bin/db_search/DBListFiles.pl?did=3&tid=38354&vid=20

the file name which I would like to download is air.sig995.2013.nc

and if its downloaded manually the link is:

ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis.dailyavgs/surface/air.sig995.2013.nc

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [`urllib`](https://www.google.com/search?q=urllib&oq=urllib&aqs=chrome.1.69i59j69i57j69i59j69i60l2.12407j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to retrieve the file

like this:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

where `url` is the url of the download and `filename` is the what you want to name the file

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Read data from an opendap server
import netCDF4
# specify an url, the JARKUS dataset in this case
url = 'http://dtvirt5.deltares.nl:8080/thredds/dodsC/opendap/rijkswaterstaat/jarkus/profiles/transect.nc'
# for local windows files, note that '\t' defaults to the tab character in python, so use prefix r to indicate that it is a raw string.
url = r'f:\opendap\rijkswaterstaat\jarkus\profiles\transect.nc'
# create a dataset object
dataset = netCDF4.Dataset(url)

# lookup a variable
variable = dataset.variables['id']
# print the first 10 values
print variable[0:10]
```

from
https://publicwiki.deltares.nl/display/OET/Reading%2Bdata%2Bfrom%2BOpenDAP%2Busing%2Bpython